# Isolated webserver using wifi on pi zero

Tags: gpio, wifi, web-server, home-automation, wifi-direct

I have a pi zero with WiFi which I have written some simple GPIO stuff on it. I want to operate it from my mobile phone, isolated from home network.

For that I want to have a php webserver that can execute linux commands  where I send HTTP request to the webserver and it will do some stuff like this, or ideally the webserver will show me a page with some buttons to press.

```
http://ipaddress/?gpio=12?state=1
```

So the keyword here is, the pi zero should advertise its own SSID like a modem/router (or what is the correct term) and I can connect to it by connecting to that SSID with username/password.

Myquestions:
Is this called HotSpot or AccessPoint? what is the correct term here?
Is it possible to do on pi zero-w ? if not what about pi 3?
Where can I find more info on this topic.

Comment: `what is the correct term` ... AP (access point)

Answer (score 1):

There are literally hundreds of tutorials on setting up an [Access Point](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md) - on the Foundation website and this Forum.

Similarly there are many on setting up a [Web Server](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/README.md)

Unfortunately controlling GPIO from php is not easy, as GPIO access requires root access permissions and php normally limits access for security reasons.

There are many tools for controlling GPIO remotely e.g. [PiGPIO](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) and I believe there are some programs for controlling GPIO from an app.

You can use VNC or ssh on your phone to control the Pi.

Comment: You are right: There are "hundreds of tutorials", most of them outdated and none working "out of the box". Happy about any hint.